# iOS App: Possible to make keyboard recommendations?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

In an iOS application, is it possible to make own keyboard suggestions if the user taps a specific UITextField? The suggestion should only appear if the UITextField is empty.

By keyboard recommendations I mean the Predictive Keyboard:

[image]

Swift code is preferred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can provide suggestions to the actual keyboard so they get presented, but what you can do is write your own inputAccessoryView to be there instead, and handle the tapping/appending of text yourself, and possibly disable the completion from the keyboard. This is essentially what the messaging apps do to present a bar with buttons to add photos and attachments when writing.

[image]

Since you don't mention what you're trying to accomplish I don't know if this would make sense. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on how to do this in code.

Comment: My only intention was to bring suggestions to the standard Apple Predictive Keyboard. If this is not possible I gonna do it myself as you said. Thanks for answering my question!